# [python]: Convert pandas column of dictionary items to individual rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a pandas DataFrame which looks like below:

```
date_time    country  src_type  edges
2021-05-01   DE       home      {"home": 10, "nav": 3}
2021-05-03   IN       nav       {"support": 1}
2021-05-04   AE       cart      {"chat": 1, "about": 4, "home": 5}
2021-05-07   US       about     {}
```

The column `edges` is a dictionary containing mapping of an edge `dst_type` to its value `edge_count`. I'd like each individual item in the dictionary be a separate row in the DataFrame.

This is more clearer when looking at the expected output:

```
date_time    country  src_type  dst_type  edge_count
2021-05-01   DE       home      home      10
2021-05-01   DE       home      nav       3
2021-05-03   IN       nav       support   1
2021-05-04   AE       cart      chat      1
2021-05-04   AE       cart      about     4
2021-05-04   AE       cart      home      5
```

The last row in the original DataFrame is dropped because the dictionary in `edges` is empty.

```
date_time    country  src_type  edges
. . .
2021-05-07   US       about     {}
```

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
records = []

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    for dst_type, edge_count in sorted(row["edges"].items()):
        records.append(
            (row["date_time"], row["country"], row["src_type"], dst_type, edge_count)
        )

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    records, columns=["date_time", "country", "src_type", "dst_type", "edge_count"]
)
```

However, this is extremely slow as looping over a DataFrame takes time. I'd like to *vectorize* this operation and make it fast. Any pointers or advice?

I'd appreciate any help on this as it would optimize our processing to be much faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to convert the dictionary to new columns with dict keys as column labels.  Then use [`.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to convert the new columns to individual rows.  Sort by `date_time` column as required using [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). Finally clean up those rows without value (or with `NaN` value) in the resulting `edge_count` column using [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), as follows:

```
df2 = df.drop('edges', axis=1).join(pd.DataFrame(df['edges'].tolist()))

(df2.melt(id_vars=['date_time', 'country', 'src_type'], var_name='dst_type', value_name='edge_count')
    .sort_values('date_time')
    .dropna(subset=['edge_count'])
)
```

Result:

```
     date_time country src_type dst_type  edge_count
0   2021-05-01      DE     home     home        10.0
4   2021-05-01      DE     home      nav         3.0
9   2021-05-03      IN      nav  support         1.0
18  2021-05-04      AE     cart    about         4.0
14  2021-05-04      AE     cart     chat         1.0
2   2021-05-04      AE     cart     home         5.0
```